# How to draw line with line segment tool from an end point in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, line-art

When I draw a line with my line segment tool in Illustrator and want to draw another line from any end point my cursor show selection tool instead of a + sign. To draw I need to select another tool and then line tool again, then it shows a + sign to add a line from any point. Why does it happens? I need a solution. Please help me out.

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to do exactly what the pen tool does: draw complex lines/shapes by gradually adding anchor points where you want them.

Comment: what application. If illustrator disable the new object handles.

Answer (score 2):

The Line tool in Illustrator is *not meant* to draw a series of connected paths. It's meant to draw a line, that's all.

If you need to draw something which is a series of straight paths, you can use the **Pen Tool**, holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to create lines at 90°, 0°, or 45°. Or merely "click" to create straight paths. In addition, you can adjust the `Constrain Angle` and `Construction Guides` (with Smart Guides turned on) in the **Preferences** to change the angle available with `Shift`.

Answer (score 0):

So you’re making a line segment. And then you want to start a new one segment that begins at the same point at the end of the other line segment.

There are two options… Create a new wire and walk the previous later enjoy your segment. Or lock the object you just drew.

It has to be this way… Imagine if the reverse were true… That you drew a line segment and then click the end of the line segment and we’re not able to add anything to it. If an element is there and you click on location then it’s going to be active. So you have to lock it.